# I want to know how to change the Tab Control style

Tags: c#, themes, tabcontrol

I'm playing around with C# and I'm using the TabControl, I would like to know how can I change the "looks" of the default tabcontrol from this:

[image: Default]

to something "smoother" and nicer, something like this perhaps
[image: Modified]

How would I do this ?

at the moment I'm using Windows Forms Application

Comment: You will need to owner-draw them or, better, write your own..

Comment: I'd suggest using the more powerful **WPF** technology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to *customize* the tab control in Windows Forms Application. 
You will have to create your own control..

Refer to [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/91387/Painting-Your-Own-Tabs-Second-Edition) to get started

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Metroframework](https://thielj.github.io/MetroFramework/) for changing style of tabs,buttons,progressbars and etc.